# Display Custom Field Value on Admin Page Column

Tags: plugins, functions, pages, admin

What I want is to display the value of the custom field called 'page_template'. I use the code below but it displays nothing under Page Template column although I have already defined a value for the page_template custom field of the page

```
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'column_page');
function column_page($defaults) {
    $defaults['column_template'] = 'Page Template';
    return $defaults;
}


function page_template_field() {
    $custom_field_id = get_post_meta($post_ID);
    if ($custom_field_id) {
        $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($custom_field_id,'page_template');
        return $custom_field_value;
    }
}  

add_action('manage_pages_custom_column','column_page_content',10,2);
function column_page_content($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'column_template') {
        $column_template_list = page_template_field($post_ID);    
        if ($column_template_list) {
            echo '<p> '. $column_template_list .' </p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main errors where the missing of the `$post_ID` parameter in `page_template_field` and using `$custom_field_id` instead of `$post_ID`.

Anyway, this works and is simpler:

```
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'column_page');
function column_page($defaults) {
    $defaults['column_template'] = 'Page Template';
    return $defaults;
}

add_action('manage_pages_custom_column','column_page_template',10,2);
function column_page_template($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'column_template') {
        $custom_field_values = get_post_meta($post_ID,'page_template');
        if (!empty($custom_field_values)) {
            echo '<p> '. join(', ',$custom_field_values) .' </p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your function declaration should have an argument:

```
function page_template_field($post_ID) {           //Here $post_ID is the argument you are passing
        $custom_field_id = get_post_meta($post_ID);
        if ($custom_field_id) {
            $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($custom_field_id,'page_template');
            return $custom_field_value;
        }
}
```

With out the argument `page_template_field` wouldn't know what `$post_ID` is!!